# Sentinel2 picture download, the resolution is not high quality

Tags: gdal, extents, gdal-translate, wmts, download

I want to download a JPEG from this service:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export?bbox=25.158691,43.381098,30.267334,48.421910&size=1024,1024&format=jpg&imageSR=4326&bboxSR=4326&f=image

the download works perfectly, it downloads exactly the BBOX area I was looking for, but the resolution is very high and you can't really see anything.

Does anyone know how I could reduce the resolution of the download from SENTINEL-2 WMTS or another source where these images can be downloaded for free?

I tried like this:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -outsize 1024 1024 "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export?bbox=25.158691,43.381098,30.267334,48.421910&size=1024,1024&format=jpg&imageSR=4326&bboxSR=4326&f=image" /var/www/html/test/out2.jpeg
```

Comment: In WMS you know the resolution that you will get beforehand because it is exactly defined by the bbox, width, and height parameters. Decreasing bbox or increasing width and height will give better resolution. The server may have been configured to block such requests, though.

Comment: The Export tool for World_Imagery isn't a WMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "resampling" option in gdal_translate to reduce the resolution. For example, to reduce the resolution to 50% of the original size, you can use the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -outsize 512 512 -r bilinear "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export?bbox=25.158691,43.381098,30.267334,48.421910&size=1024,1024&format=jpg&imageSR=4326&bboxSR=4326&f=image" /var/www/html/test/out2.jpeg
```

Note that different resampling methods can produce different results, so you may want to experiment with different methods to see which one works best for your needs. Some commonly used resampling methods include nearest neighbor, bilinear, and cubic convolution.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `size=1024,1024` seems to return a higher resolution image. However, the max size seems to be limited to 4096. [Your example link with `size=4096,4096`](https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export?bbox=25.158691,43.381098,30.267334,48.421910&size=4096,4096&format=jpg&imageSR=4326&bboxSR=4326&f=image)